# fgets not copying first letter

Tags: c, fgets

i wrote this code:

```
            check_name = 0;
            printf("Enter the Location of the photo:\n");
            fgets(location, MAX_LOCATION_SIZE, stdin);
            printf("Enter the name of the photo:\n");
            count = 0;
            while (check_name == 0)
            {
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    printf("The name is already in the list!\nChoose another one:\n"); // will not do it only for the first time
                }
                getchar;
                fgets(name, MAX_NAME_SIZE, stdin);
                check_name = checkName(frameList, name);
                count++;
            }
```

I will explain what is everything now:

I did the `check_name` cause I am doing a test to check if the name is already in a list (It doesnt really matter for this problem so I won't upload the code unless you will really need it)

I put `getchar` before the `fgets` because without it, its not even asking for the name.

Everytime that I enter something to the `fgets(entering a name)`
its not copying my first letter (If i put Dexter its saving exter) and i have already checked that i gave it enough place (`char name[50]` - my teacher told as that this will be the max)

Comment: `getchar;` or `getchar()`???

Comment: if `getchar;` didn't foist at least a warning, you need to turn up your warning levels on your compiler switches. You should have gotten something to the effect of "Expression result unused" or some such.

Comment: Please, post complete compilable examples that you have already run and tested locally to show the exact problem you have.... or we can be months trying to find what are you talking about (and in addition you don't know where the error is, so it's difficult you transmit it if you don't post **the exact code you wrote**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getchar() will receive one character and rest of the character is available to fgets(). so remove that.
if your having problem with losing one character first time... put getchar() before the loop. or even you can write `scanf("%*c");`

Comment: `getchar;` is an expression with an unused result, not a function call.

Comment: yes. in given code segment it is an expression. but the question says he is using getchar `I put "getchar" before the "fgets" because without it, its not even asking for the name.`  make the prompt to appear and its taking one character. An expression cannot make it happen so that must be a call. If its a call then arises that problem.

Comment: `getchar;` will mostly give a compilation error about some identifier not defined anywhere (or invalid type of object, in case you have included the right header file and the compiler has a prototype for it) Please, send complete compilable code examples and refuse to send code snippets.  Snippets only reflect your idea of what is happening, and not what **actually** happens (and of course, in your idea probably the error is not included, not being a concept misunderstanding)